# FullCalendar Switch View

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have JQuery FullCalendar plugin working on the webpage.  I have the display default to the Month View when the page first loads.  Also, after setting selectable: true the user can select the dates in the Month View.  At this point if the user selects the Day View from the top menu, I would like to show the day view (agendaDay) of the selected date to the user.  But, currently the day view of the current day shows up. Here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        selectable: true,
        unselectAuto: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: {
            url: 'CalendarJSON.aspx',
            type: 'POST'
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: having same requirement with react-fullcalendar component

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar store the date setting at initialization with the variables year, month, date.

```
// example initialization (calendar is the fullcalendar object)
calendar.fullCalendar({
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        unselectAuto: false,            
        firstDay:1,
        defaultView:defaultv,
        slotMinutes:30,
        year:selected_year,
        month:selected_month,
        date:selected_day,
...
```

You can change this values in the select handler.

Then i have a function which returns this values (entire date)

```
//calendar is the fullcalendar object
function check_fc_date(calendar){
    date = new Date(calendar.fullCalendar('getDate'));
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    day = date.getDate();

    alert(year+" "+month+" "+day);
}
```